# WKB approximation problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, semiclassical, ground-state

I have some issues on solving this problem: use the WKB method to estimate the ground state energy of a particle of mass $m$ that moves in a three dimensional potential $V(r)=kr$, where $k$ is a constant.
I would use the following formula:
\begin{equation}
\int_{r_1}^{r_2} dr p(r) = (n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\hbar
\end{equation}
but I can't understand how to estimate the turning points $r_1$ and $r_2$.